# When I create a new project in xcode 11 it goes without storyboard and if I run old project it comes without controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xcode11

New Project

[image: new project]

Old Project

[image: old project]

When I create a new one or go on old one I cannot use the storyboard at all. Any help please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Now i can not load storyboard or do any thing on it and the pictures above shown every thing what can i do ?

Comment: If your project doesn't have a storyboard just add one

Comment: I can not add any thing to it with drag and drop it changes for xcode11 ?

Comment: This is because you have opted to use Swift UI, which creates the views in code, not in a storyboard. Look in your `SceneDelegate`. it uses a `UIHostingController` to load `ContentView`

Comment: what is the difference between them and what is the best to go on with ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select User Interface as Storyboard while creating a new project in Xcode 11.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If someone cannot found Language option when creating new project, please make sure you choose **iOS Application** instead of **Multiplatform Application**
[image]